# Java thread on resultset oracle

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, resultset, multiple-resultsets

I am new to java. I am trying to create program to throw value to ResultSet in different thread.

```
     ResultSet rset = stmt
            .executeQuery("select  DISTINCT  substr(file_type,1,3) from DBM.file_table where process_time= '0015' ");

while (rset.next()){    
    r = rset.getString(1);
System.out.println(r);
```

Now suppose we get 5 different value from ResultSet. What i wanna do is to run below code for all value of ResultSet synchronized in different Thread.

```
    String spCall = "call DBM.SP_MS_" + r + "('0015', NULL, SYSDATE, 'DBM')";

    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        stmt1 = dbConnection.createStatement();

        System.out.println(spCall);

        stmt1.executeUpdate(spCall);

        System.out.println("SUCCESS for File_Type " + r );
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(spCall);

        stmt1.executeUpdate(spCall);

        System.out.println("SUCCESS for File_Type " + r );
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not using a [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proceed as follows:

```
public void executeQuery()
{
    ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select  DISTINCT  substr(file_type,1,3) from DBM.file_table where process_time= '0015' ");

    while (rset.next())
    {    
        final r = rset.getString(1);
        System.out.println(r);
        Thread th = new Thread ( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                method(r);
            }
        });
        th.start();
    }
}
public synchronized void method(String r)
{
    String spCall = "call DBM.SP_MS_" + r + "('0015', NULL, SYSDATE, 'DBM')";

    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        stmt1 = dbConnection.createStatement();

        System.out.println(spCall);

        stmt1.executeUpdate(spCall);

        System.out.println("SUCCESS for File_Type " + r );
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(spCall);

        stmt1.executeUpdate(spCall);

        System.out.println("SUCCESS for File_Type " + r );
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
    } catch (SQLException e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are going in the right direction? You are using a stored procedure already, so why not have a stored procedure do all of the work? At that point it should be a single call to the database:

```
CALL DBM.SP_MS('0015', NULL, SYSDATE, 'DBM');
```

Internally to the Oracle Stored Procedure, you would then do whatever was actually being done individually by the `_ + r` versions; it receives the '0015' just the same as the original call anyway. This would simplify your Java side, and it would create a much smaller connection burden against the database (rather than going back and forth).

The stored Procedure could then return a list of File Types, `r`, that it affected, which you could use for logging or reporting purposes.

How this works internally depends on what the `_ + r` implementations are actually doing. I would suspect that it's the same.

Finally, doing so would mean that, if you actually wanted to still `Thread` off the call, then you would only need to create a single `Thread` for the overall invocation. This leads to less `Thread`s in the system, which is generally a good thing.

Also, as you are new to Java, look into `Executor`s and jtahlborn's link.